# Is it safe to store secret keys in a .env file in my heroku server?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, dotenv, secret-key

Here my question is who can actually access the files that are in a Heroku server?
If i have some secret keys that i use as Env variables is it safer to store them in a file (i'm actually using the package dotenv storing my keys into a .env file ) or is maybe better to store them into the Heroku env variables system ?

Comment: this question isn't on topic for SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic it would make more sense to ask on the security site: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good practice is to store them in the [ConfigVars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars): they are separated from the code and are 'safe' in case someone gains access to the files of the application.

Locally it is ok to use `.env` (with the package dotenv) but the file is typically never pushed or stored with the application. If you are using dotenv the application will read the Heroku environment variables instead.